# PHP - Get substring after last occurrence of needle not including needle

Tags: php

If I have `abcxyz.doc` for example and want to return the extension minus the dot, so just `doc` as a substring. I cannot rely on the extension always being 3 chars.

```
<?php
$x = 'abcxyz.doc';
ltrim(strrchr($x, '.'), '.');
```

Is this the best I can do, or is there a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: Since this has been shut down, I have to answer here please up-vote comment if useful echo $ext = pathinfo($x, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`$ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) that already does that for you :)

Comment: @sjagr Thanks for the edit, will try to remember about it for future answers :)